# Scala 3 with strict equality and explicit nulls - Proper way to deal with pattern matching and Option

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, option-type, scala-3

To make this code compile (Scala 3.2.2 with `-language:strictEquality` and   `-Yexplicit-nulls`):

```
val cause: Option[Throwable] = None
cause match
  case c: Some[Throwable] => c.value
  case None => null
```

I add this line:

```
private given CanEqual[Option[Throwable], Option[Throwable]] = CanEqual.derived
```

However after looking at this:
https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/12419
I suspect there is a more proper (and concise) way to deal with the issue but couldn't understand what that is.

Comment: It compiles [just fine](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/K52dkozmTGyllfMLSzj4Xw) for me in 3.2.2. without `given`

Comment: @Dima Yes, sorry I dismissed your first example too quickly. You are right. I didn't notice that what actually breaks it for me is adding also -Yexplicit-nulls. As can be seen here https://scastie.scala-lang.org/45CUvfhaTmOrE2iL0hQU3g

Comment: @DmytroMitin you are right too. Please see the comment above, I didn't notice that the issue is caused by -language:strictEquality together with -Yexplicit-nulls. Could this be a bug that I need to report?

Comment: just do not use nulls. You don't need them in scala. Problem solved :D

Comment: A `CanEqual[Throwable, Throwable]` also [fixes](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7gCJOJJCTBiTLdSPpOsf6g) it. The error message is pretty unhelpful though, this is a really weird issue.